# align items using css flexbox with read more button at the bottom

Tags: css, flexbox

[image]

this is the default structure of two side by side divisions,
I want to keep the read more button at the bottom of the screen even the content is less.

```
 <div class="row">
<div class="col-12"> Image </div>
<div class="col-12"> 
<h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
<p>all the content which will be strecth to full height</p>
<a>Read more</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Also when i make row 100% heigth and align item : strecth, I am getting space between two columns.
[image]

Comment: Could you take advantage of the [Card Deck](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/card/#card-decks) component in Bootstrap and use the footers of the cards to contain the buttons?... If not, I can provide an answer without the use of Card Decks but I'd ask you to provide you HTML and CSS to replicate the component in the picture above

Answer (score 2):

As pointed by [IvanS95](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8437694/ivans95), you can use [Card Deck](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/card/#card-decks) component of Bootstrap. If you really want to use the flexbox on your own probably below solution can be helpful.

The below solution uses **Bootstrap 4.4.1**

You can view the working [code pen solution here](https://codepen.io/hirengondhiya/full/GRJBEre)

```css
.image-style {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container py-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 p-2 d-flex flex-column  justify-content-start">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/250" class="image-style" />
      <h4 class="px-2 mt-2">Lorem ipsum title</h4>
      <p class="px-2">
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium ab inventore corrupti fugiat aperiam beatae nisi quod mollitia, soluta dolorum sequi blanditiis delectus ex impedit quia? Expedita eius libero adipisci!
      </p>
      <p class="px-2">
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus, fugit. Fugit iure qui expedita, necessitatibus beatae quaerat distinctio soluta quam ut enim doloremque mollitia ratione illo officiis, quibusdam fuga voluptate.
      </p>
      <p class="px-2">
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas architecto odit repudiandae libero ex, neque modi explicabo quia delectus qui natus officiis nihil autem sit alias ab odio quisquam. Perferendis?
      </p>
      <a href="#" class="px-2 mt-auto">Read more</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 p-2 d-flex flex-column  justify-content-start">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/250" class="image-style" />
      <h4 class="px-2 mt-2">Lorem ipsum title</h4>
      <p class="px-2">
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium ab inventore corrupti fugiat aperiam beatae nisi quod mollitia, soluta dolorum sequi blanditiis delectus ex impedit quia? Expedita eius libero adipisci!
      </p>
      <p class="px-2">
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus, fugit. Fugit iure qui expedita, necessitatibus beatae quaerat distinctio soluta quam ut enim doloremque mollitia ratione illo officiis, quibusdam fuga voluptate.
      </p>
      <a href="#" class="px-2 mt-auto">Read more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In above html inside row there are two 6 unit wide columns that can sit side by side. Each column is converted to flex box using d-flex class, flex direction is set to column using flex-column class and using set the justify-content using justify-content-start class. Now, if I set margin-top to auto on read more button it will always stick to bottom.

To make sure the image width does not create problems I have set the image-style class on the image element which is defined as follows,

**CSS**

```
image-style {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with code that @Hiren suggested but you also don't need to use a flexbox if you don't want to. Here is an example of how you can achieve the wanted layout:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/250" class="image-style" />
            <h4>Lorem ipsum title</h4>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium ab inventore corrupti fugiat aperiam beatae nisi quod mollitia, soluta dolorum sequi blanditiis delectus ex impedit quia? Expedita eius libero adipisci!
            </p>
            <a href="#" class="read-more-button">Read more</a>
          </div>            
        </div>  

      <div class="col-6">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/250" class="image-style" />
            <h4>Lorem ipsum title</h4>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium ab inventore corrupti fugiat aperiam beatae nisi quod mollitia, soluta dolorum sequi blanditiis delectus ex impedit quia? Expedita eius libero adipisci!
            </p>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium ab inventore corrupti fugiat aperiam beatae nisi quod mollitia, soluta dolorum sequi blanditiis delectus ex impedit quia? Expedita eius libero adipisci!
            </p>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium ab inventore corrupti fugiat aperiam beatae nisi quod mollitia, soluta dolorum sequi blanditiis delectus ex impedit quia? Expedita eius libero adipisci!
            </p>
            <a href="#" class="read-more-button">Read more</a>
          </div>            
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.card {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.read-more-button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 15px;
}
```

As you can see, I added padding to the parent element (`card`) and an absolute position to the 'read more' button. This is how we did it when there was no flexbox.

Note that I still use the Bootstrap (which is flexbox).